# как распарсить результат regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть строка вида `Пн.: с 10:00 до 18:00 (обед с 13:00 до 14:00), Вт.: с 10:00 до 18:00 (обед с 13:00 до 14:00),` необходимо получить `10:00` и `18:00` в 2 группах для дальнейшего форматирования. Написал такое выражение

```
\(.*?\)|((([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]))
```

но оно находит результат только по 1 значению, и приходится костылять чтобы соединить их, как сделать норм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И `c`, и `до` можно использовать для привязки к числам. Например так:

```
/с\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+до\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+/
```

Пример работы тут https://regex101.com/r/y903IB/1

Comment: а если не завязываться на буквах, и сделать более универсальный вариант, то можно так ? или есть вариант лучше?
'\(.*?\)|.*?\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{2}).*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+'

Comment: @Сергей, можете и так как вы написали https://regex101.com/r/y903IB/2

Comment: На этой строке работать не будет корректно `Пн.: с 10:00 до 18:00(обед с 13:00 до 14:00), Вт.: с 10:00 до 18:00 (обед с 13:00 до 14:00),`

Comment: @Visman Или вот такая строка,  `Пн.: с 10:00 до 18:00 (обед с 13:00 до 14:00), Вт.: с 10:00 до 18:00 (обед с 13:00 до 14:00),10:00 до 18:00`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, ага, переадресуйте свои строки автору вопроса. Он вам ответит.

Comment: @Visman конечно так то же сделал

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта регулярка ищет именно то что вы хотите:

> /(10:00)(((?!10:00).)*)(18:00)/

А вот [тут](https://regex101.com/r/obbgKQ/1/) можете проверить.

Comment: Очевидно автору вопроса нужно любое время встреченное в нужных местах, а конкретно эти числа только для примера, иначе бы он не писал массу `[0-9]` ...

Comment: @Mike да, вы правы, этот ответ частный вариант только

Comment: @Mike Да но тогда надо нормально сформулировать вопрос и сказать например что мне нужны даты которые между от и до.